# keep zero on left using BC calc

Tags: bash, shell, logic, calc, bc

I'm having a problem using shell script.
I try to move every files older than the date I pass by parameter (as #2 from folder passed as #1), I currently use

```
#/bin/bash 
cd $1       # Parameter 1:
for i in * 
do 
var=$(echo $(ls -l --time-style=+%d%m%y $i) | awk '{print $6}' | bc) 
temp=$(echo $2 | bc) 
if [ $var -lt $temp ] 
then 
cp $i /home/igor/olders 
fi 
done
```

but the problem is when the date is before day 10. I don't know how to make this number bigger than the orders, like 01/07/16 will be smaller than 13/06/16. Can someone help me?

Comment: You could use `find` for this.

Comment: Where is the date passed as parameter here?

Comment: @sjsam the date is passed as parameter when you call the script, like $ script 130616

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use the alternative suggested in the comment:

```
find -newerXY reference
```

Quoting the [manpage for find(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find):

> Compares the timestamp of the current file with reference. The
>   reference argument is normally the name of a file (and one of its
>   timestamps is used for the comparison) but it may also be a string
>   describing an absolute time. X and Y are placeholders for other
>   letters, and these letters select which time belonging to how
>   reference is used for the comparison.  
> Some combinations are
>   invalid; for example, it is invalid for X to be t. Some combinations
>   are not implemented on all systems; for example B is not supported on
>   all systems. If an invalid or unsupported combination of XY is
>   specified, a fatal error results. Time specifications are interpreted
>   as for the argument to the -d option of GNU date. If you try to use
>   the birth time of a reference file, and the birth time cannot be
>   determined, a fatal error message results. If you specify a test which
>   refers to the birth time of files being examined, this test will fail
>   for any files where the birth time is unknown.

If you want to stick to your script simply change the format for the `ls` command. You currently use `--time-style=+%d%m%y` when you likely want `--time-style=+%y%m%d` (needs the same style as a parameter or a switch within your script).